# Generating Sinusoid Signal of 40khz

Tags: arduino-uno, pwm, frequency, signal-processing

I would like to generate a sinusoidal signal of 40kHz using Arduino Uno.
Maximum I could generate was 1kHz, using bit banging, fast PWM. Do you have ideas of how to boost it to 40kHz?

I used "Advanced Arduino Sound Synthesis" for inspiration. https://makezine.com/projects/make-35/advanced-arduino-sound-synthesis/

Comment: What kind of resolution (both amplitude an time resolution) are you wanting?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what do you mean by the time resolution, but I am planning to feed the signal into a transmitter and receive it on the other end. I use speakers that work at 40kHz frequency as both transmitter and receiver.

Comment: Time resolution: how many samples per second (or samples per sinewave period) do you want?

Comment: i mean, based on Nyquist rate, I guess it should be 2*40khz at least. But otherwise, no preference

Comment: That would give you a square wave. It depends on what quality you want. Anything less than say 128 samples per period would end up in something more like a triangle wave.

Comment: Draw a single period of a sinewave on a piece of paper. Split it into sections by drawing vertical lines. Each line is one sample. How many do you need to draw (subdivide each segment each time) before the points where the lines cross the sinewave look like a sinewave.

Comment: i would try to find an opamp-based sine wave generator circuit, then use a digital pot to adjust that. or use an ESP32's DAC...

Comment: The purpose of my project now is to develop a lock-in amplifier essentially using only arduino. Thus, I'm trying to stay away from the external hardware

Comment: if you don't need to adjust the frequency, a tuned capacitor can turn a square wave into a sine wave.

Comment: I tried adding a band pass filter after generating a square wave using arduino and the output seems pretty noisy. Any advice on how to get rid of the noise?

Comment: If you don't need to adjust the frequency there are far simpler ways of generating a signal than waveform synthesis.  But before you get too worried about the generation, consider the lock-in itself: are you going to do that in the analog domain?  To do it digitally, you probably want an MCU with a better ADC.

Comment: you could use this as a peripheral to the arduino ... https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/cypress-semiconductor-corp/CY8CKIT-059/428-3390-ND/5184557 .... here is a tone generator app note ... http://www.cypress.com/documentation/application-notes/an69133-psoc-3-psoc-5lp-easy-waveform-generation-wavedac8-component

Comment: @ChrisStratton what MCU would you recommend for that purpose? And what are the simpler ways. Essentially, for my project I need to use as much of Arduino's own hardware as possible, but I can choose any arduino on the market.

Comment: You can't really pick a platform without a complete performance requirement.  Sure, if it has to say "Arduino" in soldermask, you could see if the specs of a Due are better in the areas you need - but you won't really know what you need without detailed examination of the requirement.

Comment: @Chris Stratton, for this project the only requirement I have is to make use of Arduino as much as possible to essentially assemble a lock-in amplifier. Thus generating a 40khz sinusoid is the first step I have to make. Why 40 kHz? Because I need to use 40kHz speakers(receiver and transmitter) that operate at that frequency

Comment: Voting to close as the asker has refused multiple requests to provide any performance specification which could be used to determine if a given method will yield satisfactory results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first do some maths.

- You want 40,000 cycles per second.
- Each cycle needs splitting up into samples. For example, let's use 128 samples.
- Assume you want an 8-bit amplitude resolution.

Each second of signal would need 40,000 cycles * 128 samples. That's 5120000 samples per second.

If using PWM to generate the audio that's 256 clock cycles (2<sup>8</sup>) per sample. That means 5120000 * 256 = 1,310,720,000.

That means a "carrier frequency" of over 1.3GHz.  There's no way an Arduino can do that.

If instead you used a simple DAC (e.g., an R-2R ladder) connected to the 8 pins of port D (that's pins 0-7 on the Uno) you don't need the 256 clock cycles per sample. That means that you have to output a new sample to PORTD 5,120,000 times per second. That's outputting at over 5MHz.

With some well crafted assembly code that *might* be possible.  The Arduino certainly won't be able to do anything else at all at the same time.

You would be much better off using a chip that has audio capabilities and DMA. Maybe a Teensy 3.x would be a better choice for your project.

Comment: That seems reasonable, I'll research into that. Thanks a lot

Comment: You don't need anywhere near 128 samples per cycle; in fact you only need 2. Using so many just makes the analog cleanup filter simpler.

Comment: With 2 samples you can only generate a square wave. Yes, you can then add extra circuitry to remove the higher frequency components, but as you say it's more complex. The question is about generating a sinusoid, not generating a square wave and converting it to something close-ish to a sinusoid.

Comment: If let's say you decide to take 10 samples per period instead of 180, the sinusoid is still supposed to look decent. But that gives you 10*40,000*256 = 102MHz clock, but Arduino only has 16MHz clock.

Comment: Any number of samples is kind of ludicrous on such a small MCU.